# App doesn't work when build for Adhoc

Tags: iphone, launch

I'm facing very strange problem - my app is working nice on a device when build with Debug configuration, but when it's build for AdHoc distribution, it does nothing when started. It simply shows blank screen, no log messages on console, no errors nothing, so I don't have a clue of what's going on, what makes me desperate.

I examined all possible configurations, but without success.

Does anybody experienced such behavior? Any help is highly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: do you have any compile-time statements that could be affecting it during `applicationDidFinishLaunching`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved - iWasRobbed was right, my colleague made some changes to the code, enclosing complete startup sequence to condition valid only for Debug configuration build :)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but glad to hear it works now :)